# How to secure user uploaded files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, architecture, file-upload

I have asp mvc project. And in it I have added directory structure:

```
...
  UserUploads
    User_1
      Images
        Original
        Thumb
        Display
    User_2
    User_n
...
```

How to make this folder structure invisible to users? I don't want that unauthorized users see this images by typing url. Each user has it's own images and only user that is 'friend' of some user can see it's images. I inspected facebook images and image address is like:

```
http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/296040_2530953916384_1329592446_32898884_1499197273_n.jpg
```

So what is the best practice to make user uploaded files secure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use 2 approaches :

1. real security - restrict access to the folder structure entirely, and use only some HttpHandler (or MVC action) to serve them (after evaluating access rights, writing them to response via TransferFile or stream writer..). This is very bad from performance point of view - no caching, entire server side processing for each and every picture, etc..
2. "obfuscation" security - simply generate filenames that cant be guessed (Guid is good candidate), so nobody without access to page that will generate their filename into HTML cant access them directly. Sure, if one "friend" access it, and then give the file URL to unauthorized person, but he can as easily send him the file itself... This way the performance is very good - files are cacheable (by IIS and by client), your app doesnt have to process requests for images, etc.

Comment: That with file name as GUID is good idea. So images on the web can't be completly secured. Now I take image of my friend on facebook and logged out and I can access that image. Wired but if works for fb it works for me too.

Comment: I use GUIDs for filenames too, keeping association with real path in db. Each and every time a file is requested, I perform translation of GUID to server side path, access file and provide it, without showing the upload path (whis is actually out of IIS content domain).

Comment: Real security can also be ACL based if the users are Windows authenticated.

Comment: Please don't use obfuscation as a security method.

Answer (score 1):

Just restrict access in web.config file for that UserUploadsFolder:

```
<location path="UserUploads">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: But when some user login to application then he is authorized. Can he see it's images? And then he can see path to some image and then he can guess path to someone other image? Am I right?

Comment: No, if you put deny = * - nobody except you application will see the images

Comment: This is only true when runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is set to true.  Direct file requests do not go thru the asp.net pipeline.